# How to determine if volume is already existing in OpenShift 3?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

Im trying to create a step in my Jenkins pipeline wherein I would like to determine if a volume is already existing, if it is not existing then i will issue an oc set volume dc/mydeployment-config ... command, if its already existing then i will just use the --overwrite option.

I'm looking at jsonpath to determine if the expected name of my volume is already there, here is what i have right now.

```
$.spec.template.spec.volumes[?(@.name == 'mydeployment-volume')].name
```

I also tried this

```
oc set volume dc/mydeployment-config -o jsonpath={'$.spec.template.spec.volumes[?(@.name == 'mydeployment-volume')].name'}
```

The error was

```
error: --list and --output may not be specified together
```

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction to determine the correct

```
oc set volume
```

command to use? Or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Since your checking volumes on a DC, why not just use oc get DC with your -o jsonpath?

Comment: @WillGordon I was able to implement this based on your comment. If you put an answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find volumes attached to a DeploymentConfig, you should be using `oc get dc`, so something like

```
oc get dc/mydeployment-config -o jsonpath={'$.spec.template.spec.volumes[?(@.name == 'mydeployment-volume')].name'}
```

should show you if your volume is already attached to this DeploymentConfig.

---

If you simply just want to see the volumes that already exist, you can run

```
oc get pv
```

to see all the persistent volumes created.